Arithmetic content of proofs
Using some variant of Gödel numbering, we can turn mathematical propositions into integers (say $m$). The existence of a proof of such a statement can then be formulated in an arithmetic way, something like $\exists n, P(n,m)$ where $P$ itself can be defined arithmetically.
This procedure of "arithmetization of mathematics" is generally introduced to demonstrate Gödel incompleteness theorem.
Now given any theory (say differential geometry for instance), we could use such a numbering to turn any theorem into an arithmetical statement: something about integers.
My question is: are there some interesting arithmetical results we can obtain by looking at things from this perspective?

I cannot image what this arithmetic statement would be for, say the Hopf-Rinow Theorem in differential geometry. Something useful about integers?

I don't think so. In your third paragraph you ignore the difference between a proposition $P$ and the claim that there exists a proof of $P$ but this distinction is crucial; this arithmetization stuff is all about proofs. The way the arithmetization works is roughly that you tortuously force arithmetic into simulating a Turing machine, so the arithmetic statement you get by arithmetizing "there exists a proof of [some theorem in geometry or whatever else]" is this incredibly complicated hack that simulates a Turing machine searching for such a proof.
You don't learn anything about arithmetic from doing this to a specific statement; the resulting arithmetic statements are incredibly complicated and totally opaque except for the fact that you know they were constructed to be these simulations. If, somehow, you were to give this statement to a brilliant alien mathematician who didn't know it was specifically constructed in this way, maybe they would be able to deduce the structure of the simulated Turing machine searching for a proof. But this doesn't have "arithmetic content," really.
